# When should I stop my threads when a control is beeing destroyed (TCustomControl descendant)

Tags: multithreading, delphi

My TCustomControl descendant uses threads and this involves invalidating with InvalidateRect. I encountered that when I close the program when the thread is working I would not stop the threads in the Destroy because even before I enter the first line of Destroy of my component (where I usually signal and wait for threads to stop working), the code from the threads makes the program showing exception "Control ... has no parent window" probably on a Handle request.

Comment: First line of attack is surely to move all GUI to the GUI thread where it belongs. Then the problem just goes away.

Comment: @David_Heffernan, If I forward this event to the gui thread I still need Handle for example for PostMessage. There's Synchronize, but I don't like relying on the main thread's queue just for synchronizing.

Comment: Well my point is that you should lose the thread altogether

Comment: @DavidHeffernan good point, a responsive UI can be achieved by faster hardware - it's christmas time ;)

Comment: @mjn, I can't recall the term, there's a kind of multi-tasking that not about speeding up, but allowing the UI working while updating some elements. The simplest case is icons of the texts. When you work with threads, you can show the question mark and request the thread for image loading (hd/web/anywhere)

Comment: @Maksee But you need to put the UI in the GUI thread. You are living in denial if you think that you can access a VCL component directly from another thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All window interaction - like a call to `InvalidateRect` - is supposed to be done in the main thread, so synchronize it from the supporting to the main thread or get rid of the extra thread.

Secondly, when a control is being destroyed, you cannot use its window handle anymore because it maybe gone already. The VCL will try to recreate the handle again in such a case, although the control is being destroyed, resulting in all kind of errors. If you apparently or must have drawing instructions which are possibly called during the control's destruction, then put this check around that code:

```
if not (csDestroying in ComponentState) then
```

This code of course has to be in the main thread too! (not because window handles are already destroyed, but because the VCL isn't thread safe). Which is implied, as the code that follows - the painting - is (now) in the main thread too.

Comment: @Maksee `Destroying` in `BeforeDestruction` runs first! I don't know why `Destroying` is also in `Destroy`. Point is that you can always trust on `csDestroying in ComponentState` to prevent things from happening at any point from the beginning of destruction.

Comment: Finally I found that setting cdDestroying for all the controls of the project starting TApplication triggered on DoneApplication so all components will acquire this state before any Window handle is destroyed and even before any Destroy or BeforeDestruction call

Comment: You cannot check `ComponentState` from a thread without a dangerous data race

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I understand this concern, VCL is not thread-safe generally speaking, probaly I will do some synchronization, the answer is accepted also because it mentions synchronization

Comment: No amount of synchronization on your side can make the VCL synchronize too. All VCL access in the GUI thread.

Comment: @Maksee Yes, `DoneApplication` will be called when the program ends. Nevertheless, `BeforeDestruction` will be called on (all) individual objects that are destroyed anyway (it's VCL magic).

Answer (score 1):

That is a standard error when `TWinControl.Handle` property is accessed from a thread - an underlying window is recreated in a thread's context.

Strictly speaking it is unsafe to access `TWinControl.Handle` from a thread, though the problem usually appears at some corner cases like closing an application.

`TWinControl` class also provides protected `WindowHandle` property. You can read the value without forcing the window handle to be created. It can accessed from a thread if your component derived from `TWinControl` (or `TCustomControl`) provides access to it.

Comment: 'TWinControl class also provides protected WindowHandle property that never recreates an underlying window' - GREAT!  ABOUT TIME!  how long has Delphi had this feature?

Comment: @MartinJames - I don't know how long, it exists in Delphi XE.

Comment: @Serg I was confused by your original wording of the final paragraph. I know what you mean now. I've clarified the wording. I would still disagree with your final sentence. You can't avoid a data race when accessing `WindowHandle` from a thread. You can read a value in the thread at the same moment that the GUI thread is changing the value. So the `WindowHandle` should only ever be accessed in the GUI thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I did not say that `WindowHandle` is valid if you read it from a thread, only that the underlying window is never recreated in a thread context, so reading `WindowHandle` from a thread never raises exceptions.

Comment: @MartinJames It's present in D5. Smart money says it was present in D1.

Comment: A better way to handle this is to give the thread its own `HWND` member that the component updates (with proper synchronization with the thread) from its overriden `CreateHandle()` and `DestroyHandle()` methods. That way, the thread always has a valid and up-to-date `HWND` to work with. In general, an `HWND` has an affinity to the thread it is created in, but that does not mean that other threads cannot use the `HWND` at all, because they can, as long as they are not perform thread-specific operations on them (and `InvalidateRect()` is not thread-specific).

Comment: Otherwise, you could just `PostMessage()` a custom message to the `HWND`, and let its message handler call `InvalidateRect()` on the thread's behalf.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer still makes sense, but I just came with an object that can be useful with multi-threading and VCL (TVCLMutex), so it's partly answers my own question. The trick is that I create another window in the main thread so it shares the same message queue. Since then, waiting in its own messages makes VCL magically safe, at least in most of the cases (because all the code comes directly and indirectly from the same queue). So if your threads want to access/change something in VCL, create a single instance of TVCLMutex and wrap unsafe access code in its Access/Release and you can be sure the main thread is somewhere in the windows core waiting to continue processing messages and nowhere else.

```
unit VclMutex;

interface uses Windows, Messages, SysUtils;

const
  WM_WaitInMainThread = WM_USER + 1;

type
  TVCLMutex = class
  private
    fVCLWaitEvent: THandle;
    fAccessAvailEvent: THandle;
    fWnd: HWnd;
    fThreadId: Cardinal;
    fLevel: integer;
  protected
    procedure   WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor  Destroy;override;
    procedure   Access;
    procedure   Release;
  end;

implementation uses Forms;

{ TVCLMutex }

constructor TVCLMutex.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;

  if GetCurrentThreadId <> MainThreadId then
    raise Exception.Create('The object should be created in the main thread');

  fWnd:=AllocateHWnd(WndProc);
  fVCLWaitEvent:=CreateEvent(Nil, false, false, Nil);
  fAccessAvailEvent:=CreateEvent(Nil, false, true, Nil); 
end;

destructor TVCLMutex.Destroy;
begin
  CloseHandle(fVCLWaitEvent);   
  CloseHandle(fAccessAvailEvent);

  DeallocateHWnd(fWnd);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TVCLMutex.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  case Msg.Msg of
    WM_WaitInMainThread:
      begin
           { ReplyMessage make return from SendMessage call called from other thread }
        ReplyMessage(0);

           { Waiting to release VCL (main thread) queure. Signal will come from the
             Release method of working thread  }
        WaitForSingleObject(fVCLWaitEvent, INFINITE);
      end
    else
      Msg.Result := DefWindowProc(FWnd, Msg.Msg, Msg.wParam, Msg.lParam);
  end;
end;

procedure TVCLMutex.Access;
var
  AThreadId: Cardinal;
begin
  AThreadId:=GetCurrentThreadId();

  if GetCurrentThreadId = fThreadId then
  begin
      { If owning thread then allow while keeping nested level }
    Inc(fLevel);
  end
  else
  begin
       { Waiting for section to be available (from other threads) }
    WaitForSingleObject(fAccessAvailEvent, INFINITE);

       { Owning thread }
    fThreadId:=AThreadId;

       { Ask main thread queue to wait }
    if fThreadId <> MainThreadId then
      SendMessage(fWnd, WM_WaitInMainThread, 0, 0);

    fLevel:=1;
  end
end;

procedure TVCLMutex.Release;
begin
  Dec(fLevel);

  if fLevel = 0 then { All nested releases passed  }
  begin
        { Signaling for queue to release (if different thread) }
    if fThreadId <> MainThreadId then
      SetEvent(fVCLWaitEvent);

    fThreadId:=0;
       { Signaling that the mutex section is available }
    SetEvent(fAccessAvailEvent);
  end;
end;

end.
```